# wordpress-woocommerce rest api is so slow

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to create 100k products in woocommerce through woocommerce rest api.

But it takes too long to get response from woocommerce. It takes almost 3 minutes per 100 data.

It's normal situation? or Is there any way to solve this issue?

help me please. Thank you in advance.

```
const CreateToWP = function (data) {

let data_batch = {
    create: []
};

data_batch['create'].push(data)

return WooCommerce.post("products/batch", data_batch)
.then((res) => {
 console.log(res.data.create.length)
```

})

Comment: Speed depends on the website speed. If your server is connected via a 
bamboo pipe to the internet or has bad hardware, you can run into problems. In your case I would check the server resources with the `htop` command and improve the website speed. You can find a lot of articles about this topic in the internet.